# Is there any advantage to a particular boot order when using UEFI?

Tags: windows-7, ssd, bios, uefi

Just built a system with motherboard that supports the UEFI. I didn't realise what it was at he time and was interested to know why it appears to be attached to a 1TB HDD. I have in my system room for extra storage and not on the SSD where the OS is.

The BIOS lists in the boot order:

- the UEFI HDD
- the optical drive
- a 4TB drive
- the SSD 
  and finally a repeat of the 1TB listed at the top with the UEFI,
  (this repeat listing does not carry the UEFI tag on it).

The mainboard is a Gigabyte GA-H97-Gaming 3.

Is there any advantage in rearranging this configuration? E.g., is there any choice on where the UEFI is and does it matter?

Comment: Have a look at this thread http://superuser.com/questions/584701/what-are-the-disadvantages-of-not-using-uefi-boot which might help you with some idea.

Comment: @mic84, as for [your edit](http://superuser.com/revisions/951016/3): please don't abuse quotes and line breaks for formatting. (An explicit line break [is seldom appropriate in English text](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45617/why-should-users-have-to-press-return-twice-to-insert-new-lines/45635#45635).) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

EFIs have built-in boot managers. Their user interfaces vary greatly, from completely useless to moderately useful, but the key point is that each entry in the built-in boot manager tells the firmware how to launch one program (normally a boot loader). These boot manager entries are stored in NVRAM. Ordinarily, when you install an OS, it creates an EFI boot manager entry that points to the OS's own boot loader. Thus, with an OS installed, you should see an entry for that OS in the boot manager list.

Many EFIs also automatically generate entries for things like network-boot options, the firmware setup utility, a built-in EFI shell, BIOS/CSM/legacy-mode boot of disks, and fallback boot loaders on hard disks and removable disks. This last item deserves some elaboration: If no OS has created an entry, EFI can boot from a standard filename: `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` (assuming an x86-64/AMD64/x64 CPU). Originally, this fallback filename was intended to enable booting from removable media, so that OS installers and emergency tools can boot. Today, though, it's often used as an emergency backup -- an OS may install a copy of it's boot loader in this location so as to enable the OS to boot in case the NVRAM entries get corrupted.

Your question isn't really 100% clear about what hardware you've got in your computer. I wouldn't be surprised to see at least one, and possibly two, entries for each hard disk that's attached to the computer. (Two would come from one EFI-mode fallback entry and one BIOS/CSM/legacy-mode entry. The latter would probably disappear if you disable the CSM in your firmware.) OTOH, one or both disk entries might be missing depending on the firmware's design and current settings, especially if there's no EFI fallback boot loader on the disk. Additional entries can be highly system-specific. It sounds like you're saying you're seeing a boot entry for booting from a network storage device. This might happen if that device supports network booting via a protocol like [PXE,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preboot_Execution_Environment) and if PXE support is enabled in your firmware.

Beyond that, if you're seeing entries for hard disks you've never heard of or for OSes you've never installed, my suspicion is that you're not the first owner of the motherboard. If a previous owner booted the system, and especially if that person installed an OS, there might be leftover entries in the machine's NVRAM.

You can manage EFI boot manager entries using utilities in the firmware itself and in many OSes:

- Many, but not all, EFIs enable you to adjust boot manager entries using their setup utilities. Details vary from one EFI to another.
- The v2 [EFI shell](https://superuser.com/questions/592854/what-is-the-efi-shell) provides a command called [`bcfg`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#bcfg) that enables editing these entries.
- In Windows, the `bcdedit` command provides a limited ability to edit these entries, and the third-party [EasyUEFI](http://easyuefi.com/index-us.html) provides an easier point-and-click interface for doing so.
- In Linux, the [`efibootmgr`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#efibootmgr) command enables adding, deleting, and adjusting EFI boot entries.

Note that poking around with EFI boot manager entries when you don't understand them can cause your system to become unbootable.

Also, most of this is irrelevant if you install your OS(es) in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. The EFI boot manager still exists, but with nothing but BIOS-mode OS install(s), the EFI boot manager is reduced to the functionality of the simple device-based boot manager in a traditional BIOS.