# Where can I download a legitimate copy of Windows 8 without having to supply an activation key?

Tags: windows, windows-8, usb, installation, windows-activation

I own a Lenovo Yoga 13 ultrabook and the Windows key is stored internally in the UEFI or something like that. The windows installer automatically recognizes the key during install. Here's my issue:

I need to create a Windows 8 USB installer (ultrabook has no disc drive). One easy way is to [download the windows 8 installer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/upgrade-product-key-only) and run it. After inputting your windows key it downloads windows and gives you install options. One of those options is to create a USB installer.

I used the one windows 8 key that I had for another machine to get to the part where it generates the USB installer. It created it successfully. I booted from USB just fine and began reinstalling Windows 8 on my ultrabook. At this point it did properly detect my ultrabook's key, but the USB installer I created was for Windows 8 Pro because the key I had was for Windows 8 Pro. However, the internal ultrabook's key is NOT for windows 8 pro. It tells me it cannot find a valid windows image for the key I supplied.

I assume if I supplied a regular windows 8 key to the downloaded installer then it would have generated a regular windows 8 USB installer. I just don't have a regular windows 8 key other than the one stored internally.

Bottom line is I need to create a regular windows 8 (not pro) USB installer. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the problem with the installed Win8? Did you try Refresh or Reset? There are no other legit sources besides what you've mentioned and MSDN.

Comment: Yeah I created a recovery USB drive but when I go to refresh or reset it oddly prompts me to "insert my installation media". I tried pulling out the USB and putting it back but it says my media is invalid. It's very strange.

Comment: We've had many similar questions (such as [this one](http://superuser.com/questions/493766/where-can-i-download-windows-8-legally-from-microsoft)) asking for Win8 download sources. There are no Digital River links yet, so either download using a Win8 Core/Std key, or borrow a disc from someone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only download the Windows 8 **Pro** upgrade (and yes, you'll need a valid product key)

There is no direct download for Windows 8 (*Digital River*) right now.

You can always call Lenovo to ask for a recovery disk (or ask them about how to access the recovery partition). [www.lenovo.com/contact/us/](http://www.lenovo.com/contact/us/)

Comment: Recovery partition is a fail and I asked Lenovo for recovery discs. They say I need to pay them over $100 to send it in and have it re-imaged >:(

Comment: If you call Microsoft and explain the situation they may send you a Windows 8 disk (I think they'll also charge you for shipping and handling).