# Reinstall Samsung OEM Windows 8, no recovery partiton or disk

Tags: windows-8, iso-image, oem

I have a recently purchased samsung NP540U3C that came with Windows 8 pre-installed. Windows stopped working and the recovery partition doesnt work anymore. I used RWeverything to find the Windows product key but it cannot be used to install a retail version of Windows when using the Microsoft Windows 8  setup. According to [this](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130215025739AAXKwgM) Windows 8 would automatically activate if it is reinstalled but its not possible to download from Microsoft with an OEM Key. Samsung would not provide at recovery image/disc, so I am wondering if it was possible to dowhload windows 8 with the OEM key and recover Windows.

Is there something similar to [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457078.aspx) except for Windows 8?

Edit: Can you the change the Windows 8 Enterprise Eval to install Windows 8 Core?

Thank You

Comment: Which ISO have you used? You must use a MSDN/Technet ISO or an ISO without a **ei.cfg** file on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I download Windows 8 legally, from Microsoft?](http://superuser.com/questions/493766/where-can-i-download-windows-8-legally-from-microsoft) There's no way to download the ISO (which is for the Upgrade version of Win8 Pro anyway) from MS using the OEM key. You'll have to contact Samsung, or obtain the setup media from somewhere.

Comment: Is it possible to edit the ei.cfg with the Enterprise Eval to install Windows 8 Core instead of Enterprise?

Answer (score 2):

I know how to fix it. It's easy, make a image recovery (if your F4 recovery works [follow this](http://www.rodneybeede.com/Creating_Samsung_recovery_disc_on_a_Windows_8_laptop.html)) in a USB 32 GB Flash drive and change the settings in your BIOS to

Secure Boot = Disabled 
Boot UEFI  
Advanced -> DEP = Disabled

**Boot Priority**

USB FDD 
USB HDD
Media CD

Put the USB flash drive in the laptop and wait a minute, then you should see the recovery contract and license agreeament and the blue Button **Recover**

Answer (score 0):

try to re-install windows 8 again using system repair disk. if your recovery won't work then look for a friend or anyone who has windows 8 pre-installed in their notebooks and try to make a recovery drive. i hope that would fix the problem.

if you don't know how to make a recovery drive in windows 8 here's the link

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-PH/windows-8/create-usb-recovery-drive

just focus only on creating a recovery drive using USB.. ok..

Answer (score 0):

1.Try to repair /recover it by inserting any windows CD and click repair when option comes.

2.or if you know the version of windows8 with which it came pre installed just download OEM version of it and simply change the option in firmware AS SECURE BOOT:Disable and change the sub option from UEFI to cms. save changes
(Click F2 when Samsung logo comes to make changes in the firmware)

next step: make the USB bootable pendrive of the OEM version frm pc
now insert the bootable pen drive

Click start button- when samsung logo comes click f10 
Choose usb option n install windows8 then try to activate it depends it may activate if u have installed correct Windows8 OEM version or else it wont

The correct OEM version will detect the key Embeded with your BIOS and won't ask uou for a key....

If it is incorrect it will ask you for key ......

Most Samsung Windows8 LAPTOP come with Windows 8 Single LANGUAGE

So try [this link](https://kickass.to/windows-8-single-language-en-us-x64-iso-t8152425.html#main)
Donload this version of Windows 8 OEM