# i have a mac pro with no disc drive im running parallels i need a download version on windows 8 pro 64 bit

Tags: mac, windows-8

I have a mac pro with no disc drive im running parallels. I need a download version on windows 8 pro 64 bit.

where can I buy one?

I am only able to find DISC purchases. I know I could do flash drive but surely there is a way to buy a download right?

Comment: Try cleaning up the grammar a bit, and you'll likely get more responses

Comment: See [this post](http://superuser.com/questions/493766/where-can-i-download-windows-8-legally-from-microsoft)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft does not sell digital versions of `Windows 8 Professional System Builder` ( which is what you need ) the only digital version of Windows 8 is Upgrade license for `Windows 8`. There are currently no legal ways to download `Windows 8` unless you already have an `Upgrade License`.

If you have a MSDN subscription or access to `DreamSpark Pro` (aka MSDNAA) this isn't a problem.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to purchase and download the install directly from Microsoft.

Try this web site:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/purchase#1TC=t1

Comment: That is the upgrade license not the system builder license which is what the author requires to install on his OS X since he doesn't already have a windows installation.