# How to migrate a cloned linux installation into a dual-boot environment alongside Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, windows-8, multi-boot

I've got a new machine with Windows 8 installed on a HDD. I plan to switch that out with an SSD. I currently use Linux (Ubuntu) all of the time, but I'd like to keep the Windows 8 installation along-side Ubuntu dual-booted, just in case.

I don't have the new machine just yet but presumably it'll come with an OEM Windows installation disc. Then I can replace the HDD with the SSD and install Windows using the disc. But is it possible to get my current Ubuntu installation running along-side the windows installation?

I know I can use something like Clonezilla to clone Ubuntu onto an external drive, but how would I integrate that into a multi-boot setup with the Windows installation.

For what it's worth, according to an answer for [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/622587/re-install-windows-8-into-a-partition-on-a-oem-machine-for-dual-boot-ubuntu), the installations from these OEM discs usually demand that the entire space of the available drive be used, which is why I would probably need to install windows first.

I know that I could install windows, then install a fresh copy of Ubuntu and restore my home folder from my current installation, but I'd really like to have all the system files copied over too, to save me having to re-install lots of software.

Comment: simplest solution.  Install Ubuntu on the new machine, get that working, then restore an image of your current installation onto the Ubuntu partition.

Comment: So, install a fresh copy of Ubuntu in a dual-boot setup alongside the windows installation, and then overwrite the new Ubuntu installation with my current one?

Comment: You should backup the image of this new machine before you try anything clearly.

Comment: OK, but if it all goes pair-shaped, I suppose the worst case scenario is that I'll loose the clean installation of Windows (which I can re-install from the disc) and the clean installation of Ubuntu.

Comment: The above solutions are pretty good. Personally I would do the Windows installation, then clean Ubuntu to a Ubuntu restore. It's worth noting that Ubuntu isn't always able to recognize Windows 8 due to UEFI and depending on how you initially installed it (BIOS settings.) Alternatively, you can format the SSD into 2 partitions, install Windows then copy the clone (like you mentioned) and then do a Windows Startup repair or `SuperGrub2Disk` to recognize the various installed OS's. Furthermore, you can install GRUB manually assigning boot partitions and sectors, but that gets pretty technical.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion I would ,go to the KALI Linux site,and use their procedure for installing Linux and win7 as a dual boot template.their procedure works and I have done it myself successfully.I personally do not recommend and duall booting. It is too much hassle to. Fix software o/s issues later...neil neil