# Can I delete empty recovery partition (Win8)

Tags: windows-8, partitioning

I'm trying to install Linux alongside my 64-bit Windows 8 and went into my partition manager to find this structure.

[image: Image of partition structure]

In order to create partitions for my Linux install I need to free up some space. I see that the last partition is an empty recovery partition, as you can see highlighted, it's 100% free.

I was wondering is it okay to just remove this partition seeing as it doesn't appear I'll be losing anything?

Not sure if this helps but this is on a Fujitsu AH532 running Windows 8 64-bit with UEFI.

Comment: I would modify the existing D partition instead.  The recovery partition shouldn't be touched.

Answer (score 1):

The recovery partition is normally not free; it's normally full, and holds the files and tools needed to re-install Windows. Thus, it appears as if that partition may have been damaged or modified already. If so, you might want to take extra care to keep backups of your Windows installation, so as to enable you to restore Windows in case of problems. Alternatively, if you've got a [retail Windows 8 DVD,](https://superuser.com/questions/493766/where-can-i-download-windows-8-legally-from-microsoft) you should be able to use that to restore the installation. In either of these cases, deleting the recovery partition should be OK.

That said, you might want to shrink your `C:` partition to make room for Linux, especially if you want a big `/home` directory. Although 15GB is enough space to hold Linux, it's not enough for a big Linux installation, especially not if you expect to store big user files on a Linux filesystem.

Note that an EFI-based installation uses GPT partitions, which aren't limited to four primary partitions the way MBR partitions are. Thus, you'll be able to create several new partitions for Linux, if that's your concern, without causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

Recovery partition lets you reinstall windows with all the default crapware quickly, without installing from DVD and looking for drivers. Windows not recognizing it doesn't really mean it is empty.

If you did a clean windows install, got recovery dvds or disk came with your laptop - you don't really need recovery partition.