# Windows 8.1 fails to boot after removing the recovery partition

Tags: boot, windows-8.1

I wanted to get some space for my Ubuntu, [the reply here](https://superuser.com/questions/656048/can-i-delete-empty-recovery-partition-win8) said it's fine to delete the recovery partition. So I deleted it, installed Ubuntu in its place.

Since the bootloader is not working (yet, I need to set it up - some clever guy came up with the idea to set up 32-bit UEFI there and it requires a little of tinkering) so the Windows Boot Manager is the device to boot from.

But Windows says that a medium is inaccessible and the computer needs to be repaired. The error code is `0xc0000225`. I can only enter UEFI

Is there any way to tell the system to simple forget the missing recovery partition? I don't want to overwrite the MBR since I'll be setting up Grub soon.