# I removed the SuperFish root certificate and now I get certificate errors on most websites

Tags: ssl-certificate, superfish

I removed the SuperFish root certificate from my Lenovo Yoga Pad Pro based on advice from [What is the superfish SSL certificate and where did it originate](https://superuser.com/questions/880062/what-is-the-superfish-ssl-certificate-and-where-did-it-originate).

Now when I go to web sites in IE and Chrome I get certificate errors.
Does anyone have advice how to fix this?

Comment: You need to remove the SuperFish spyware as well.

Comment: Uninstalling Superfish Visual Discovery fixed the certificate errors.  thank you.  I guess I missed the obvious part :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure you uninstall any instances of Superfish or Visual Discovery under Programs and Features in the Windows Control Panel.   They're still trying to use the bad certificate you just removed.

Answer (score 1):

Run the [SuperFish Removal Tool](https://github.com/lenovo-inc/superfishremoval/) by Lenovo.

> This utility will completely analyze your system for this problem and remove the SuperFish application, associated registry entries, files and security certificates, if needed.